# Flip the ACTUAL plot result in MATLAB.

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, axes

I think this might be simple. If we simply plot a vector in MATLAB, it will show it normally, going left to right. That is, the x-axis will have 'time'.

But, I would like to show it going from up to down instead in the plot. How can I do that? In other words, I want the amplitude to be shown on the x-axis, and the time to be shown on the y-axis.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vector with the coordinates of your time vector `t` and flip x and y in your call to `plot`:

```
plot(t, 1:length(t));
```

Comment: @Learnaholic no problem, note that I wrote it wrong the first time, see edits.

Comment: I think you had it right the first time - I tried what you wrote the first time and it works perfectly...

Comment: @Learnaholic all is well then.